# Multiple php-fpm versions on LAMP Server

Tags: php, linux, apache2, linux-mint

(With the tutorial and afterwards with the help of Thomas Christlieb)

The configuration used right now is the following :

```
System runs on an "old" HP EliteBook, 
which should run as test server before going live + backup server
SystemOS : Linux Mint 18.3 (based on Ubuntu 16.04)
Access to Site via Windows PC in same Network
```

To install the LAMP Server + fpm modules, I followed this steps :

1. `sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-utils mysql-server phpmyadmin`
2. `sudo a2dismod php7.2 (which was installed with phpmyadmin)`
3. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
4. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
5. `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi libapache2-mod-fcgid`
6. `sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mysql php5.6-zip php5.6-gd php5.6-xml`
7. `sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mysql php7.0-zip php7.0-gd php7.0-xml`
8. `sudo a2enmod actions`
9. `sudo a2enmod fastcgi`
10. `sudo a2enmod fcgid`
11. `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
12. `sudo a2enmod suexec`
13. `sudo a2enmod include` (a2enmod's just to check if they are already enabled)
14. `sudo service apache2 restart` (to restart the server so everything will be loaded correctly)
15. created 2 files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, one `php56.conf`, one `php70.conf`
16. created 2 directorys in `/var/www/html`, one PHP 5.6, one PHP 7.0
17. `sudo a2dissite 000-default` (disable default site)
18. `sudo a2ensite php56 php70` (enable PHP 5.6 & PHP 7.0 site)
19. `sudo service apache2 restart`
20. /etc/apache2/sites-available/php56.conf :

    ```
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>

        AddHandler php56-fcgi-www .php
        Action php56-fcgi-www /php56-fcgi-www

        Alias /php56-fcgi-www /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi-www

        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi-www -socket /run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization

        <Directory "usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

    </IfModule>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName php56
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/php56
        <Directory "/var/www/html/php56">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            SetHandler php56-fcgi-www
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log
        CustomLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
    ```
21. /etc/apache2/sites-available/php70.conf :

    ```
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>

        AddHandler php70-fcgi-www .php
        Action php70-fcgi-www /php70-fcgi-www

        Alias /php70-fcgi-www /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi-www

        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi-www -socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization

        <Directory "usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

    </IfModule>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName php70
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/php70
        <Directory "/var/www/html/php70">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            SetHandler php70-fcgi-www
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log
        CustomLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
    ```
22. In both PHP 5.6 & PHP 7.0 Directories I created a file `info.php`

    ```
    <?php phpinfo() ?>
    ```
23. `sudo service apache2 restart` (to reload the changed configuration)

---

So now the LAMP Server is installed with `php5.6-fpm` & `php7.0-fpm` but now my first problem occurs.

When I open PHP 7.0 Site in Web browser it shows me the correct `phpinfo()` which tells me :

> PHP Version 7.0.27-1 + ubuntu16.04.1 + deb.sury.org + 1
>      Server API FPM/FastCGI
>      Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini ...

---

But when I open the PHP 5.6 site in web browser it shows me the exact same `phpinfo()` output. 
So I tried disabling the PHP 7.0 site to check whether or not my PHP 5.6 config might be corrupt.

```
sudo a2dissite php70
sudo service apache2 reload
```

---

Now when I open PHP 5.6 (same for PHP 7.0) it shows me the `phpinfo` for PHP Version 5.6 like this :

> PHP Version 5.6.33-3 + ubuntu16.04.1 + deb.sury.org + 1
>   Server API FPM/FastCGI
>   Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini ...

---

From there on I asked Thomas Christlieb for help and with his instructions I made the following :

1. `a2dissite php56 php70` (to disable both site configuration files)
2. `a2ensite 000-default` (to enable the default configuration file again)
3. Made the following modifications to '/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf'

   ```
   <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
       AddHandler php56-fcgi-www .php
       Action php56-fcgi-www /php56-fcgi-www
       Alias /php56-fcgi-www /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi-www
       FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi-www -socket /run/php5.6-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
       <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
           Require all granted

       </Directory>
       AddHandler php70-fcgi-www .php

       Action php70-fcgi-www /php70-fcgi-www
       Alias /php70-fcgi-www /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi-www
       FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi-www -socket /run/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
       <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
           Require all granted

       </Directory>

   </IfModule>
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
       <Directory "/var/www/html/php70">
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           SetHandler php70-fcgi-www
       </Directory>
       <Directory "/var/www/html/php56">

           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           SetHandler php56-fcgi-www
       </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. `sudo service apache2 restart` (to reload the new configuration)

So but now when I open both sites, I get the exact same error Message 'Internal Server Error', but those two messages are in a different font, 
which I suppose could mean that it should work like this, because otherwise they should be exactly the same, or am I wrong?

I googled around a lot, also looked up on here, but the this problem wasn't really present as I don't use docker nor Nginx in my configuration. 
Maybe someone already had a problem like this and could tell me how to resolve the last step that I am missing.

---

Access.log Information

---

```
...
100.100.100.11 - - [20/Feb/2018:08:26:14 +0100] "GET /php56/info.php HTTP/1.1" 500 805 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
100.100.100.11 - - [20/Feb/2018:08:37:35 +0100] "GET /php56/info.php HTTP/1.1" 500 805 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
...
```

---

Error.log Information

---

```
...
[Tue Feb 20 09:30:08.166199 2018] [fastcgi:error] [pid 27475] (2)No such file or directory: [client 100.100.100.11:52772] FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi-www": connect() failed
[Tue Feb 20 09:30:08.166574 2018] [fastcgi:error] [pid 27475] [client 100.100.100.11:52772] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi-www"
...
```

---

This is what I noticed now while looking trough the `Error.log` but I don't know why it says so. 
I checked the status of `php5.6-fpm`, `php7.0-fpm`, `apache2`, they are all 3 active (running) so I can't help myself anymore and need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So no more need for an answer, Thomas Christlieb found the problem now.

In my 000-default.conf the FastCgiExternalServer i had a wrong path inside.

He changed /run/php5.6-fpm.sock to /run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock

and /run/php7.0-fpm.sock to /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock

and now everything works just fine as it should.

Thanks.